# C# TableLayoutPanelCellPosition transfer

Tags: c#

greetings, i need a replacement for TableLayoutPanelCellPosition. i have made this class:

```
public class GridUnit
{
    public GridUnit()
    {
        Column = 0;
        Row = 0;
    }

    public GridUnit(int column, int row)
    {
        Column = column;
        Row = row;
    }

    public int Column { get; set; }

    public int Row { get; set; }
}

private TableLayoutPanelCellPosition homeLastPositionFirst = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 0);

private GridUnit homeLastPositionLast = new GridUnit();
```

and if i do:

```
homeLastPositionLast = homeLastPositionFirst
```

i get errors and this is expected. my question is what else do i need to implement so that i can do this?

thank you for your time and just for the record im new at this.

Comment: i want to use GridUnit instead of TableLayoutPanelCellPosition to maintain code portability i.e. not dependant on windows forms from the Model point of view in MVC.

Comment: @ikurtz: It is typically best to edit the question to add extra information rather than add a comment, because the information will more visible on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to maintain code portability, you will need to convert your `GridUnit` into `TableLayoutPanelCellPosition` when you want to use it.  You could implement static methods to do the conversion for you.

```
static GridUnit ConvertToGridUnit(TableLayoutPanelCellPosition position)
{
    return new GridUnit(position.Column, position.Row;
}

static TableLayoutPanelCellPosition 
    ConvertToTableLayoutPanelCellPosition (GridUnit gridUnit)
{
    return new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(gridUnit.Column, gridUnit.Row;
}
```

You would use the conversion methods like this:

```
GridUnit homeLastPositionLast = ConvertToGridUnit(homeLastPositionFirst);
```

Even better, you could turn the conversion methods into conversion operators:

```
public static explicit operator GridUnit(TableLayoutPanelCellPosition position)
{
    return new GridUnit(position.Column, position.Row;
}

public static explicit operator TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(GridUnit gridUnit)
{
    return new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(gridUnit.Column, gridUnit.Row;
}
```

Then you can cast between GridUnit and TableLayoutPanelCellPosition:

```
GridUnit homeLastPositionLast = (GridUnit)homeLastPositionFirst;
```

If you wanted to allow free conversion between GridUnit and TableLayoutPanelCellPosition without explicit casting, you would change `explicit` into `implicit` in the converstion operator.  Then you could do this:

```
GridUnit homeLastPositionLast = homeLastPositionFirst;
```